# How do I Access fields from one table through another table in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

Please how do I link and access the fields:  'location' and 'building_type' from Property table in Client table. (I want to be able to get the 'location' and 'building_type' information for Client table from Property table  )

```
class Property(models.Model):
    location = models.CharField(choices=Property_Location, max_length=120)
    building_type= models.CharField(choices=Property_Type, max_length=120)


class Client(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    phone = models.IntegerField()
    location=()
    building_type =()
```

I tried using PK & related_name for both, but it ended up showing me just the details of
'location' for both the location and building_type fields

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a [`ForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) in the `Client` model that refers to the `Property` model, like so:

```py
class Property(models.Model):
    location = models.CharField(choices=Property_Location, max_length=120)
    building_type= models.CharField(choices=Property_Type, max_length=120)


class Client(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    phone = models.IntegerField()
    property_f = models.ForeignKey(Property, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

You can set any option on [`ForeignKey.on_delete`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete) according to your need.